# Live RX and TX rates in linux

Tags: c++, python, c

I'm looking for a way to programatically (whether calling a library, or a standalone program) monitor live ip traffic in linux. I don't want totals, i want the current bandwidth that is being used. I'm looking for a tool similar (but non-graphical) to OS X's istat menu's network traffic monitor.

I'm fairly certain something like this exists, but I'm not sure where to look, and i'd rather not have to reinvent the wheel.

Is it as simple as monitoring a socket? Or do I need a utility that handles alot of overhead for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have byte and packet counters in /proc/net/dev, so:

```
import time

last={}

def diff(col): return counters[col] - last[iface][col]

while True:
  print "\n%10s: %10s %10s %10s %10s"%("interface","bytes recv","bytes sent", "pkts recv", "pkts sent")
  for line in open('/proc/net/dev').readlines()[2:]:
    iface, counters = line.split(':')
    counters = map(int,counters.split())
    if iface in last:
      print "%10s: %10d %10d %10d %10d"%(iface,diff(0), diff(8), diff(1), diff(9))

    last[iface] = counters

  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: And on a 2.6 kernel, there's more detailed per-device statistics in `/sys/class/net/$dev/statistics`

Answer (score 1):

I use a little program known as [`dstat`](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/) It combines a lot "stat" like functions into 1 quick output. Very customizable. It will give you current network throughput as well as much more.

In linux the program `netstat` will give you raw network statistics. You could parse these stats yourself to produce meaningful output (which is what dstat does).

Answer (score 0):

You can get network throughput and packet counts using the following `dstat` command:

```
dstat -n --net-packets -f 10
```

Or if you want to monitor specific interfaces, you can do:

```
dstat -n --net-packets -N eth0,wlan0 10
```

If you prefer the more conventional `bits per second` output:

```
dstat -n --net-packets -N eth0,wlan0 --bits 10
```

This will provide you with 10 second averages. If you prefer to write this out for post-processing, you can export to a CSV file using:

```
dstat -n --net-packets -N eth0,wlan0 --bits 10
```

Dstat ships with a lot plugins to correlate these metrics to other metrics in your system, and it gives you the flexibility to add your own (python) plugins if you need to customize data or monitor something specific to your environment.